# Unable to make changes to specific files in .NET Core 3.1 scaffolded identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have scaffolded the Identity files in my .NET Core 3.1 MVC project and I can edit most of the files in the `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account` directory but any changes I make to the `Register.cshtml.cs` and `RegisterConfirmation.cshtml.cs` are not reflected when debugging in VS for Mac. Also in VS for Mac I can't edit the `RegisterConfirmation.cshtml` or `Register.cshtml` files, however they exist in the `Account` directory when I navigate to it outside of VS. Is there a reason why these specific files seem to have some sort of restriction?

[image]

Comment: When you say "not reflected" you mean that you e.g. add a new line of text to the cshtml but then when you rebuild the proect and run it again, it doesn't appear in the website render?

Comment: I don't see Register.cshtml in your screenshot; are you sure it's included in the project? On Windows I would click SHOW ALL FILES on the solution explorer, right click the file and choose Include In Project. I don't know what you'd do on a mac for that. I suspect hat because they're not included in the project they aren't output to the folder where the site runs and possibly their related code files aren't included in a compilation(?)

Comment: @CaiusJard I did what you said and now everything seems to compile properly. I guess my only question now is why aren't those files added to the project after the scaffolding is finished.

Comment: I think that's one of those things where "if it happens once, I'll make a note, happens again, I'll enable logging and actually go looking the third time.." :-)

Comment: @CaiusJard gotcha sounds good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the commentary diagnosis, it seemed that some files were present in the directory of the solution but not included in the project. Ensuring they were included and built made things work as expected